# The argument type of request callback in nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require('http');
var req = http.request({host:"www.google.com"})
req.on("response",function(res){
    // ***IncomingMessage***
})
```

why the type argument of callback is IncomingMessage? how to get from native code?
This is the link of github: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v0.12/lib/http.js

Comment: What do you want to say exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of the `http` and `https` modules, see:

- https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback
- https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#http_http_request_options_callback

> The optional callback parameter will be added as a one time listener for the 'response' event.

The 'response' event is described here:

- https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_response

and it gets the instance of `http.IncomingMessage` passed:

- https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage

> An IncomingMessage object is created by http.Server or http.ClientRequest and passed as the first argument to the 'request' and 'response' event respectively. It may be used to access response status, headers and data.
>
> It implements the Readable Stream interface, as well as the following additional events, methods, and properties.

Everything that you describe is perfectly in sync with the documentation.

Comment: Thank you， but how to know further in native code， such as why it implements the Readable Stream interface and why IncomingMessage object is created by http.Server or http.ClientRequest